# NodeJs Async await by default

Tags: node.js, async-await

Could be a bad practice to have all functions on a nodejs Express web app with async await syntax? (even if they not necessarily uses await methods) for example:

```
app.get(basePath, async function (req, res, next) { 
    await anyMethod().then(function () {
    })
    await anyMethod2().then(function () {
    })
});

app.get(basePath, async function (req, res, next) { 
    anyMethod().then(function () {
    })
});
```

The idea is to have allways defined like async for terms of templating or if I need to use them like this other example for best practices:

```
app.get(basePath, async function (req, res, next) { 
    await anyMethod().then(function () {
    })
    await anyMethod2().then(function () {
    })
});

app.get(basePath, function (req, res, next) { 
    anyMethod().then(function () {
    })
});
```

could be affect performance?

(I removed params and the logic of the promises for easy visualization of the question)

Comment: Why do they all have empty then callbacks? If any returned a value, you wouldn't be able to use it.

Comment: Hi, is only for reduce the code to minimun necesary (I removed the params for easy visualization)

Comment: If a call never blocks, there are no points to make it async or promise. Even make code less readable. If you refuse to aware which part of codes is blocking, you will eventually tend to write bad codes and running into trouble whenever facing related bugs.

Comment: yes that will not really necesary, but comonly mostly of my app.get requests will have promises to get data from the model (with async methods) and for fast developement I have a basic templating system with all funcionalityy (JWT, security, db acces, etc). Actually I'm adding the 'async'  word to the majority of the functions that my templating system generates. So I thougth that could be a good idea to have allways the 'async' word, but I don't know if is really a good idea

Comment: It all depends on what your functions do. You can't take one side and say its the best approach and fits to all kind of scenarios. @RickyMo explained in more detail. *For your templates*, you can prefer not to use `async/await` because developer will only add it when he needs the result of that blocking function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could be affect performance?

`async/await` impact always on performance.

If you add `async` in a synchronous function, you have a degradation of performance of 400%. [A simple banchmark](http://jsben.ch/6SpB3)

Adding `await` in Node.js <= 11 create 2 Promises at the low level, one then wrap the upper code, and another one for the next literals.
With Node.js 12 `await` will produce only one additional Promise.

v8 and Node.js are working hard to reduce this impact on performance. [V8 Article](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async) that explains how `async/await` works under the hood.

Looking your example, instead, it is not good because you are waiting for nothing:

```js
await anyMethod2().then(function () { res.reply('hello') })
```

If you don't use the result of an `await` it is pointless because the output will be **the same** in the end:

```js
await anyMethod2().then(function () { res.reply('hello') })


anyMethod2().then(function () { res.reply('hello') })
```

These two sentences produce the same result, but with different overhead (and error management).

And you have to think if `anyMethod1()` and `anyMethod2()` could be parallel or serial. In your example, you have lost the parallelism.

This is worth:

```js
const res = await anyMethod2().then(function () { return {hi:'world'} })
res.reply(res)
```

If you `await`, use the output!

Comment: Ok I see, so I'll use async only when is neccesary. Thanks